# Why do you have to declare pins at registration of a filter?

Tags: c++, directshow

When registering a direct show filter you have to (or can?) define all the pins of the filter.
But you also define them in the filter class.
Why do you have to do this twice and how do the two ways relate to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real pins are those classes derived from [`CBasePin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368685%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). They implement pin functionality and their methods receive/send data, connect to other pins, communicate to and through their owning filter.

Then registration related pin structures such as [`AMOVIESETUP_PIN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are for registration exclusively. They are not related to runtime filter operation and only help finding the filter during graph construction phase. When filter is being registered, it advertises its capabilities and caps of its pins as well. Then [Intelligent Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390342) uses this information to pick suitable filters when connecting pins that don't connect directly.